# Possible to change location.href of a div without using iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to try to do something like this, where I change the href location for a specific div. I know I can use an Iframe but I am trying to avoid frames. Is there any way to accomplish this, where a user click a button and the source of just a single div changes but the rest of the site stays the same.

```
<script>
function chdiv()
{
document.getElementById("div2").location.href="google.com";
}
</script>

<div id="div1">
<button id="change" onclick="chdiv();"
</div>
<div id="div2">
<div>
```

Comment: If you made a div act just like a frame, then what benefit you would get from avoiding frames?

Comment: it would be used for seo purposes

Comment: See my previous comment. You seem to be confusing the idea that "the things that iframes do are bad for SEO" with "iframes are bad for SEO". Building an iframe out of JavaScript (i.e. using Ajax as most of the answers suggest) isn't going to be any better for SEO, it will be worse.

Comment: depends on exactly what you are doing with SEO, if the only content in your page comes from within an iframe, the search engine will not properly pick that up, it needs to be contained in the parent document.

Comment: That isn't true, and if the content is only loaded with JS, then there's a good chance of it not being picked up by search engines.

Comment: might look into $.load() to inject a url into an element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and divs don't have a `location` property. You may look into doing an AJAX request to bring in whatever HTML you need.

```
$.get('url', function (data) {
    $('#div2').html(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response, Don't know jquery, or ajax, but if I do it this way is it possible to load an external page that takes a url query string. For example I have a php page that will only populate via url query string. When user clicks button, I want the contents of the div to load the PHP page. Not just change the html.

Comment: or does your function do this?

Comment: Yes, you can send query strings as `data` in an AJAX GET request. Take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/. jQuery takes some getting used to, but it will make your life easy. You can do this in plain JavaScript, but it's more lines of code to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe the behavior you're looking for is possible. Div's don't have a `location` property. You'll likely need to utilize AJAX to change whatever data is in the div you are looking to change.

Answer (score 0):

Not like this, but you can do it with AJAX:

```
<div id="div1">
    <button id="change">load</button>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#change").click(function(){
            $("#div2").load('http://google.com/');
       });
});
```

- You just need to be careful when loading external content, because of 
  X-Frame-Options header, take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options